# Are birthday celebrations allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, celebration

Are there any Hadith/Quran citations that refer to celebrating an individual's birthday?

Is birthday celebration allowed? If yes, what is and is not appropriate? What other basic rulings are relevant for planning one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruling on celebration of birth; Is the term 'Bidah' applicable here?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/ruling-on-celebration-of-birth-is-the-term-bidah-applicable-here)

Comment: [Did ahlul bayt celebrate mawlid?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2545/11938)

Answer (score 5):

There's a difference between scholars; many scholars say that celebrating birthday is *haram*. [Here](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/60980)'s the fatwa in Arabic.

But there are many trusted scholars who disagree and says it's halal and you can celebrate birthday **unless** it involves *haram* acts, like drinking beer or so, in which case it's *haram*.

Comment: Any reference to the second fatwa? You might also want add the relevant part of the fatwa in the answer even if it's in Arabic. Someone with Arabic knowledge might translate it.

Comment: A Pagan ritual is not halal no matter how you look at it. This is like celebrating Naw Roze, which is a pagan ritual, even though Shia scholars clearly declared their position against the ritual in the past, people continued to celebrate it, therefore recent Shia scholars are finding excuses to justify it simply because they couldn't enforce a ban. Today, a Pagan ritual is the biggest festival in Iran, even bigger than the two Eids, how can that be halal?

Comment: @RASHOMON, I approve the second past of your answer. (Although you submitted two different view of the scholars, but I assume the second part of your answer would be more logical if we celebrate it as solely a halal happiness, without haram practices. God bless you for your fair answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can survey the birthday celebration from two different angles.

You can survey and look at this (birthday celebration) as just a celebration which is not relevant to the islam as an islamic celebration, thus in that case it doesn't appear to be haram. But you can survey the matter of birthday celebration somehow as if it is relevant to islam, hence in that case it can be counted as a bid'ah. And as possibly you are aware, bid'ah is one of haram things from the view of Islam.

Answer (score -1):

> “Then We have put you (O Muhammad) on a plain way of (Our)
>   commandment. So follow that, **and follow not the desires of those who
>   know not**. Verily, they can avail you nothing against Allaah (if He
>   wants to puish you). Verily, the zaalimoon (wrongdoers) are awliyaa’
>   (protectors, helpers, etc.) to one another, but Allaah is the Wali
>   (Protector, Helper) of the muttaqoon (pious).” [[al-Jaathiyah
>   45](http://quran.com/45):[18](http://quran.com/45/18)-[19]](http://quran.com/45/19)

Full fatwa here: http://islamqa.info/en/ref/1027

Answer (score -1):

Islam may not allow birthdays to be celebrated if it goes against the sharia (law)
For example music, dancing, alcohol and anything else prohibited. The best way to celebrate your birthday is to say alhamdulilah and praise Allah for allowing you to live for another year. :)

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. That's an incomplete answer and below the standards we are seeking here. Please reread the question being asked and elaborate your answer. And also go through [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Celebrating birth dates is derived from pagan beliefs:

> “For thousands of years people all over the world have thought of a birthday as a very special day. Long ago, people believed that on a birthday a person could be helped by good spirits, or hurt by evil spirits. So, when a person had a birthday, friends and relatives gathered to protect him or her. And that's how birthday parties began.”
>
> (The World Book -- Childcraft International)

Clearly, the birthday culture is derived from pagan religion and has no place in Islam. The belief behind this practice is far from Islam, if you practiced it due to ignorance, then you're not at fault, but when you have knowledge and continue to practice pagan rituals, then you're at fault and will be brought to account in the judgement day.

Answer (score -2):

Birthday celebrations is not allowed but in Islam there is no any rules to stop your celebrations of happiness Islam is a peaceful religion.