# What to do with a birthday gift?

Tags: halal-haram

Salam brothers and sisters. It was my birthday a few days ago and my non-Muslim friend gave me a birthday gift. When she told me she was going to get me a gift, I told her that I did not need and want anything, but she still ended up giving me a gift anyway. I did not refuse the gift as she had already bought things, and I did not want to cause her trouble; I also did not want to lose our friendship. However, I know that celebrating one's birthday is haram in Islam. What should I do? The gift is not really one that can be "donated;" she gave me a bag, a notebook, and pens. Is it right for me to return the gifts (she also gave me gift receipts), give the gifts to another person (e.g. a cousin), or can I keep and use the gifts?

Thank you for your time and answer.

Comment: To begin with: [Are birthday celebrations allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2731/17163).  It's not so straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Salam. I think you can keep that gifts and also use it. And that's the new thing for me that celebrating a birthday is haram in Islam. I even don't know about it. And as you say your gift nothing but a bag, a notebook, and pens which are not haram(I think so...). If there is a thing which is haram in Islam then you have an issue. So, don't worry, don't return the gifts and no need to give that gifts to another person. Becuase If you do this you will definitely hurt that person's feelings. I hope you understand.